# Error 35584 (driver return code) generating output;

Tags: errors, xetex, pdf

I get this error when I run a code:

```
Error 35584 (driver return code) generating output;
```

and that's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\advance\topmargin1cm
\usepackage{xepersian}

\makeatletter

\ps@empty
\def\@oddhead{%
    \begin{RTL}%group
        \psset{unit=1cm}%
        \rput[tl](-4.5,2.5){\includegraphics{t1.pdf}}%
   \end{RTL}%group
\hfill
}


\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}%{AH Farvardin v8}%{XB Zar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}%{AH Farvardin v8}%{XB Zar}
\defpersianfont\siah[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}
\defpersianfont\koodak[Scale=1.2]{IRYakout}


\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}%{XB Zar}

\setlatintextfont{DejaVu Sans}


\long\def\readpic#1{s#1\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\readpic{f/41}
\readpic{f/1010f/21}
\readpic{f/1010f/20}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nobody will be able to reproduce your problem because we don't have your fonts nor your images, Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and can be reproduced by others.

Comment: I have the same issue. Error 35584. @martin-schröder here is an MWE MWE: \documentclass[preview]{standalone} \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} \setmainfont{Chalkduster} \usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext} \begin{document} Text Goes Here \end{document} I get: [1] (./latextest.aux)Segmentation fault (core dumped) ) Error 35584 (driver return code) generating output; via http://jf.burnol.free.fr/showcase.html#chk
and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412685/installing-chalkduster-fonts-in-latex