# Installing Chalkduster Fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, installing

How can I set up documents in Chalkduster:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Chalkduster}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Peraphs there is anything into this link: https://gist.github.com/xiaom/2765398.

Answer (score 2):

`XeLaTeX` is a great solution to all font issues. The code you have should work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Chalkduster} 
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
I am a poor imitation of a chalkboard
\end{document}
```

Make sure you typeset with `XeLaTeX`, not `LaTeX` (there are usually such options in your editor). You also need the Chalkduster font installed on your machine and need to use the correct name (this should show up when using a font explorer or similar). Here's the result:

[image]

[Here is](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this) a handy guide for using custom fonts.

Comment: `Mapping=tex-text` should be `Ligatures=TeX`, but it can be omitted, because the option is set by default for the main font.

Comment: This fails for me with Error 35584. Any ideas?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550440/218836